# Find inverse modulo when modulo is smaller than the number

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I know how to use the Euclidean algorithm to find the inverse modulo in most cases, but I can't wrap my head around the calculations when the modulo is smaller than the number I'd like to find the inverse for.

For example:

$$59x \equiv 1 \pmod{19} $$

has solution $$x \equiv 10 \pmod{19}$$ according to [online calculators](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~dsri/modular-inversion-answer.php?n=59&p=19) but I can't figure out why.

Comment: 59 and 1 are not congruent mod 19!

Comment: @user21820 : What does that mean? If you check the link you can see the calculation I'd like to find the steps for.

Comment: You wrote $59 \equiv 1 \pmod{19}$. That is simply false! See my answer for what you should write.

Comment: It just means that $59\cdot 10\equiv 1\bmod 19$.

Comment: By the way I didn't downvote your question but I can see why someone might for the reason I take issue with what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a solution to $59x \equiv 1 \pmod{19}$.

But $59x \equiv 1 \pmod{19} \Leftrightarrow (3(19)+2)x \equiv 1 \pmod{19} \Leftrightarrow 2x \equiv 1 \pmod{19}$.

I'm sure you can now solve the last equation, which is equivalent to the original.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept as soon as I can. What about $$19x \equiv 1 \pmod{59} $$? This method does not work then.

Comment: What method are you referring to? The algebraic manipulations I showed above is to solve your question of what to do when you want to find the inverse of $x$ mod $m$ where $|x| > m$. In any case, once you find that $59 \cdot 10 \equiv 1 \pmod{19}$, you have $59 \cdot 10 - 19k = 1$ for some integer $k$ and hence you also have found an inverse of 19 mod 59 by definition of inverse.

Comment: @OptimusCrime: Anyway if you find any answer on Math SE helpful, not just to your questions, you can upvote it.